# SphinxQL - How to order by date without a search query

Tags: sql, sphinx, sphinxql

I have the following sphinx query

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE MATCH('car');
```

This is working perfectly fine when I need to search for 'car'.

Lets say you have a search field where someone enters 'car', but what if one enters an empty string ''? In this case I want to display all results ordered by date.

SphinxQL require MATCH(..) in the query, so doing like in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

will not work.

How can I order by date without a search term?
I have tried the following with no success :(

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE MATCH('*') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actully tried running...

```
SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

? The results may surprise you :)

Comment: Where is the facepalm smiley? ... Thats it. Thanks!